# Using jQuery to display dynamic content in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having a tough time displaying content in IE11. I tried show/hide and visible/hidden. The following code works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari with the following URLs:

http://localhost/test/dynamicURL.html?v=0 (displays message for first-time visit)
http://localhost/test/dynamicURL.html?v=1 (displays message for returning visit)

I also have the following after the opening head tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But, IE11 is ignoring it and displays everything. I started to create a fiddle for this, but JSFiddle and IE11 no longer play together. Here's the test page I created locally:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("jQuery works!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("jQuery doesn't work.");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 var visitor = new URL(location);
 var newvisitor = visitor.searchParams.get("v")
 if (newvisitor == '0') {
  console.log("New visitor.") 
  $('#welcomeNew').css("visibility","visible");
  $('#welcomeBack').css("visibility","hidden");
 }
 else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
  $('#welcomeBack').show();
  $('#welcomeNew').hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="welcomeNew">
  <h1>Welcome to AT&amp;T!</h1>
  <p>We're so glad you're visiting us for the first time.</p>
</section>
<section id="welcomeBack">
  <h1>Welcome back!</h1>
  <p>We're so glad you're back!</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL API is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url) in IE11, meaning these lines will fail and lead the user to the `else {}` clause:

```
var visitor = new URL(location);
var newvisitor = visitor.searchParams.get("v");
```

**Edit:**
Here are some useful equality checks to run in your hard-coded tests.

```
let newvisitor = 0; // <-- var is fine, too, but not const

console.log('==, testing number 0 against string equality')
if (newvisitor == '0') {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

console.log('==, testing number 0 against numeric equality')
if (newvisitor == 0) {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

newvisitor = "0";

console.log('==, testing string "0" against string equality')
if (newvisitor == '0') {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

console.log('==, testing string "0" against numeric equality')
if (newvisitor == 0) {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

newvisitor = 0;

console.log('===, testing number 0 against string equality')
if (newvisitor === '0') {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

console.log('===, testing number 0 against numeric equality')
if (newvisitor === 0) {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

newvisitor = "0";

console.log('===, testing string "0" against string equality')
if (newvisitor === '0') {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}

console.log('===, testing string "0" against numeric equality')
if (newvisitor === 0) {
  console.log("New visitor.")
} else {
  console.log("Returning visitor.")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Even when I hard-code 'newvisitor' and set it to 0, and/or include 'section' in the selector, it still shows all the content, instead of just the 'welcomeNew' content.

Comment: @user3120861 Try using triple equals in the if statement comparison as I think your statement could be affected by coercion.

Comment: I tried to the triple equals. No change. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user3120861 When you're hard-coding the number in your test, how are you hard-coding it? As '0' or 0?

Comment: Thanks for the equality checks. By the way, I'm trying your examples in Dreamweaver CS6 and it's recognizing "Let", but Chrome is okay with it.

Comment: @user3120861 Use `var` if it's complaining to you.